# How to use a 256x64 OLED Display with STM32 via SPI

Tags: stm32, display, spi

I'm working on a proyect with a display with a resolution of 256x64 SPI interface, but i can't find any information about it.

Has anyone worked on this type of display?

This is the display that I'm working on https://www.mouser.cl/ProductDetail/Newhaven-Display/NHD-2.8-25664UCB2?qs=EQmeiuRlVUTjbx5MVlv5%2Fw%3D%3D

I've found the µGUI library, but I'm really new in this kind of proyect, so i don't understand the documentation about it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's unclear what you are asking. Are you looking for a tutorial? If so, this is likely the wrong place to ask. And what does your setup look like (which SMT32 chip, 3- or 4-wire SPI etc.)? And what framework (STM32cubeMX, Arduino, libopencm3 etc.) are you using?